# Error CS1501 no overload for method 'listblobs' takes 5 arguments and no overload for method 'delete' takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working with a Azure Web App site, while compiling the application these couple errors showed up.
here is the code snip:

```
protected override void DeletePictureThumbs(Picture picture)
{
    string str = $"{picture.Id.ToString("0000000")}";
    using (IEnumerator<Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.IListBlobItem> enumerator = cloudBlobContainer_0.ListBlobs(str, false, 0, null, null).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            ((Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlockBlob)enumerator.Current).Delete(0, null, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Need help in correcting the syntax

Answer (score 1):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet

`CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs(String, Boolean, BlobListingDetails, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext) Method`

You are passing 0 rather than `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobListingDetails` object.
cloudBlobContainer_0.ListBlobs(str, false, 0, null, null)

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.delete(v=azure.10).aspx

`Delete ([OptionalAttribute] DeleteSnapshotsOption deleteSnapshotsOption,  [OptionalAttribute] AccessCondition accessCondition, [OptionalAttribute] BlobRequestOptions options, [OptionalAttribute] OperationContext operationContext)`

You are passing 0 rather than `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.DeleteSnapshotsOption` object.

Comment: But according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails?view=azure-dotnet[/link]  BlobListingDetails Enum None "0" List only committed blobs, and do not return blob metadata. then pass 0 should be correct shouldn't it?, but I'm no sure

Comment: 0 is an int, not enumerated

Comment: Instead of 0 use BlobListingDetails.None

Comment: Did this answer help?